# Convert value from scientific notation to decimal in shell?

Tags: shell, awk, sed, csh

How to convert value from scientific notation to decimal in shell? (preferred C shell)

Also I'd want to convert it from e-12 to e-9 and then shell

42.53e-12 to 0.04253. I have to do this for a list.

Comment: `42.53e-12` can not be presented as `0.04253`. Also, this "*to do this for a list*" requires detailed description/sample

Answer (score 11):

`printf` will do this for you, from shell.

```
 $ FOO=42.53e-12
 $ BAR=$(printf "%.14f" $FOO)
 $ echo $BAR
 0.00000000004253
 $
```

In ancient+arcane C-shell, this would be.

```
$ set FOO=42.53e-12
$ set BAR=`printf "%.14f" $FOO`
$ echo $BAR
0.00000000004253
$
```

Answer (score 3):

## shell

Many shells (specially ancient+arcane csh) don't understand floating point arithmetic.

In most shells there is a builtin `printf` which understands "scientific format".

```
$ printf '%5.0f\n' '1e3'
 1000
```

But all printf could **not** do math:

```
$ printf '%5.0f\n' '1e3+1e3'
printf: ‘1e3+1e3’: value not completely converted
```

There is a workaround in two steps for csh. 
- First
 Convert the number to a decimal of less than 18 digits (for a 53 bit significant of a 64 bit float)<sup>[a]</sup>:

```
    % printf "%.18f\n" "42.53e-12"
    0.000000000042530000
```

- Second
  Multiply by `1e3` (as you requested) and print again:

  ```
  % printf '%.15f\n' "`printf "%.18f" "42.53e-12"`e3"
  0.000000042530000
  ```

Of course, `printf` in `csh` is an external utility with its own float size (64 bit?) and may be different for a different OS.

## Math tools.

To do math (other than the shell) it is natural to think of `bc`, but bc has its own limitations (doesn't understand the `e` as exponent, it has to be converted to `10^`). [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12882612/9110606).

But awk could do it:

```
% echo 42.53e-12 | awk '{printf("%.15f\n", $1*1e3)}'
0.000000042530000
```

Don't expect more than 15 correct digits as awk use a 53 bit significant. To have more, you need the GNU version of awk with the arbitrary precision module compiled in.

```
% echo 42.53e-12 | awk -M -v PREC=134 '{printf("%.40g\n", $1*1e3)}'
4.253e-08
```

That is 134 binary bits for (up to) 40 decimal digits. As a decimal:

```
% echo 42.53e-12 | awk -M -v PREC=134 '{printf("%.40f\n", $1*1e3)}'
0.0000000425300000000000000000000000000000
```

## list

In your question, you state:

> I have to do this for a list.

But give no details of what kind of list it is. If the list is inside a file (not as a shell variable) you need nothing from `csh` (or any other shell) except to execute this:

```
% awk '{printf("%.15f\n", $1*1e3)}' <file
```

The same precision limitations as above still apply.

---

<sup>**[a]**</sup> Actually, to be technically exact, you should limit the number of digits with the `%g` printf format first, so the pedantically correct solution is a three level transformation.

In any reasonable shell (ksh,bash,zsh) this will work:

```
$ bash -c 'printf "%.15f\n" "$(printf "%.18f" "$( printf "%.18g" "42.53e-12")" )e3"'
0.000000042530000
```

But quoting a double `` ` ` `` is really awkward in csh, and csh use `set` to assign to vars. In short, this will work for `csh`:

```
$ csh -c 'set a=`printf "%.18g" "42.53e-12"`; set a=`printf "%.18f" "$a"`; printf "%.18f\n" "${a}e3"'
0.000000042530000000
```

But, I really, really! think that you should avoid csh.

Answer (score 1):

You may try the following:

```
echo "3.0000000000e+02" | awk '{printf("%d",$0);}'
```

or if you expect to have decimals

```
echo ""3.676361000e+02" | awk '{printf("%0.2f",$0);}'
```

Answer (score 0):

Might not be the best solution but I managed to do it with a little hack. You can do something like this -

```
scientific='42.53e-12'
base=$(echo $scientific | cut -d 'e' -f1)
exp=$(($(echo $scientific | cut -d 'e' -f2)*1))
converted=$(bc -l <<< "$base*(10^$exp)")
>> .00000000004253000000
```